# Is there a way to catch when ContainsFocus changes?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I need to be able to determine when `ContainsFocus` changes on a `Control` (specifically a windows form). Overriding `OnGotFocus` is not the answer. When I bring the form to the foreground, `ContainsFocus` is true and `Focused` is false. So is there an `OnGotFocus` equivalent for `ContainsFocus`? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: GotFocus events of the child controls are fired if you have a child control. Otherwise OnGotFocus of the form is called.

If I understood the question correctly, then this should work:

```
    bool lastNotificationWasGotFocus = false;

    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeEvents(e.Control);
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsubscribeEvents(e.Control);
        base.OnControlRemoved(e);
    }

    private void SubscribeEvents(Control control)
    {
        control.GotFocus += new EventHandler(control_GotFocus);
        control.LostFocus += new EventHandler(control_LostFocus);
        control.ControlAdded += new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlAdded);
        control.ControlRemoved += new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlRemoved);

        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            SubscribeEvents(innerControl);
        }
    }

    private void UnsubscribeEvents(Control control)
    {
        control.GotFocus -= new EventHandler(control_GotFocus);
        control.LostFocus -= new EventHandler(control_LostFocus);
        control.ControlAdded -= new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlAdded);
        control.ControlRemoved -= new ControlEventHandler(control_ControlRemoved);

        foreach (Control innerControl in control.Controls)
        {
            UnsubscribeEvents(innerControl);
        }
    }

    private void control_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeEvents(e.Control);
    }

    private void control_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        UnsubscribeEvents(e.Control);
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckContainsFocus();
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckLostFocus();
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
    }

    private void control_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckContainsFocus();
    }

    private void control_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckLostFocus();
    }

    private void CheckContainsFocus()
    {
        if (lastNotificationWasGotFocus == false)
        {
            lastNotificationWasGotFocus = true;
            OnContainsFocus();
        }
    }

    private void CheckLostFocus()
    {
        if (ContainsFocus == false)
        {
            lastNotificationWasGotFocus = false;
            OnLostFocus();
        }
    }

    private void OnContainsFocus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I have the power of focus!");
    }

    private void OnLostFocus()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I lost my power...");
    }
```

Comment: I know that that should work, but OnGotFocus doesn't even get called when the form is brought to the foreground. Hence, CheckContainsFocus() won't get called. So you're left with the same problem. :(

Comment: GotFocus events of the child controls is fired if you have a child control. Otherwise OnGotFocus of the form is called. Just check if "private void OnContainsFocus()" is called or not. I did, an it is working.

Comment: I tried it and it worked. With controls on the form, the override OnGotFocus was never called, but the control_GotFocus was indeed getting called. So that was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to use a Timer. It's definitely brute force, but it gets the job done:

```
private Timer m_checkContainsFocusTimer = new Timer();
private bool m_containsFocus = true;

m_checkContainsFocusTimer.Interval = 1000; // every second is good enough
m_checkContainsFocusTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(CheckContainsFocusTimer_Tick);
m_checkContainsFocusTimer.Start();

private void CheckContainsFocusTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!m_containsFocus && ContainsFocus)
        OnAppGotFocus();

    m_containsFocus = ContainsFocus;
}
```

But is there an easier way?

Comment: Waited 12 years for anybody who needs this hint? Here I am!

Answer (score 0):

Handling the GotFocus and LostFocus events should do it.

Another thing to note... the SDK says this about the ContainsFocus property:

> You can use this property to determine
>   whether a control or any of the
>   controls contained within it has the
>   input focus. To determine whether the
>   control has focus, regardless of
>   whether any of its child controls have
>   focus, use the Focused property.

EDIT:

When handling the GotFocus event, you may still have to check the Focused/ContainsFocus property depending on how the hierarchy of your controls is set up.

ContainsFocus will be true if the control *or any of its children* have focus.
Focus will only be true if the specific control itself has focus, regardless of its children.

Comment: Sorry, but like I stated in the question, GotFocus doesn't work for this.

Comment: @MikeHall is right. GotFocus doesn't fire on the parent one of its children controls gets the focus. So, the question is still how to get an event when the parent ContainsFocus changes. Unfortunately the answer to this question only works for controls added via Controls.Add, not if the children themselves have controls added...